# One record is not inserting properly into sqlite3 database IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

In my application I'm using sqlite3 database and I'm storing the data in to the database. I have 4 fields like name,city,phone and email id the problem is the city field is not inserting into the database instead of that its taking the phone number data in city field.

```
      -(void) createTable: (NSString *) tableName
         withField1:(NSString *) field1
         withField2:(NSString *) field2
         withField3:(NSString *) field3
         withField4:(NSString *) field4;
     {
         char *err;
         NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT);",tableName,field1,field2,field3,field4];
      if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
         sqlite3_close(db);
         NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
      }else{
         NSLog(@"Table Created");
      }  
     }
```

Database Creation.

```
    [self createTable:@"reg" withField1:@"nam" withField2:@"cit" withField3:@"ph" withField4:@"em"];
```

IBOutlets.

> @synthesize name,citiy,phone,email;

Inserting the data into database.

```
  - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
         NSString *namm = name.text;
         NSString *citt = citiy.text;
         NSString *phon = phone.text ;
         NSString *eml = email.text;

         NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO reg ('nam','cit','ph','em') VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@')",namm,citt,phon,eml];

         char *err;
     if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
     }else{
         NSLog(@"Table Updated");
     }
          name.text=@"";
          citiy.text=@"";
          phone.text=@"";
          email.text=@"";
     }
```

In the above i have checked everything but I'm not able to find where I'm doing wrong in this code. Please tell me where I'm doing wrong. Its showing like this in my database.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: it sounds like you have mis-attached the iboutlets and the corresponding text fields

Comment: @Petesh i have made mis attached in the iboultels now its working f9 thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to be fine . Though I am guessing just try to print city and phon

```
     NSString *citt = citiy.text;
     NSString *phon = phone.text ;
```

If you are getting the wrong data here in then check your connection you might done wrong with your connections(IBOutlet).

Comment: Nice that your problem is solved . You can accept the answer :)

Comment: ok wil accept the answer please update the answer like mis match of the iboutlets like how petesh given in the comment...

Comment: actually I have mentioned that in the answer. I asked you to log the value just for the cross checking . My line : If you are getting the wrong data here  then check your connection you might done wrong with your connections(IBOutlet). Intends the same .

Comment: sorry thats my bad i did't see your answer fully  i have accepted ur answer